# Passing arguments with wildcards to a Python script

Tags: python, windows, command-line, arguments

I want to do something like this:

```
c:\data\> python myscript.py *.csv
```

and pass all of the .csv files in the directory to my python script (such that `sys.argv` contains `["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]`, etc.)

But `sys.argv` just receives `["*.csv"]` indicating that the wildcard was not expanded, so this doesn't work.

I feel like there is a simple way to do this, but can't find it on Google. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the glob module, that way you won't depend on the behavior of a particular shell (well, you still depend on the shell not expanding the arguments, but at least you can get this to happen in Unix by escaping the wildcards :-) ).

```
from glob import glob
filelist = glob('*.csv') #You can pass the sys.argv argument
```

Comment: It's not "can"; for windows, it's "must".

Comment: Well, you can also use os.walk so it's not strictly a must :P

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: true. os.walk seems more cumbersome than glob.  Glob's not  required, but it's so perfect a fit for this problem.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Does anyone know why Windows shells don't handle this for you?

Comment: @Ryan: Because DOS utilities were built by people who didn't know UNIX and decided to let each utility to handle the expansion instead of making the shell smarter. Awful design, but that's just one among many :-)

Answer (score 17):

In Unix, the shell expands wildcards, so programs get the expanded list of filenames.  Windows doesn't do this: the shell passes the wildcards directly to the program, which has to expand them itself.

Vinko is right: the glob module does the job:

```
import glob, sys

for arg in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
    print "Arg:", arg
```

Comment: +1. Note that this also works perfectly fine if `sys.argv[1]` is a fully specified filename instead of a wildcard. In that case, `glob.glob` just returns a list containing that very filename.

Comment: also works if you forward a parameter to your Python `script script.py c:\path\*\subdir`
glob generates a list that I can use later on. Great module!

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple wildcard items passed in (for eg: `python myscript.py *.csv *.txt`) then, `glob(sys.argv[1]` may not cut it. You may need something like below.

```py
import sys
from glob import glob

args = [f for l in sys.argv[1:] for f in glob(l)]
```

This will work even if some arguments dont have wildcard characters in them. (`python abc.txt *.csv anotherfile.dat`)

Comment: I've never seen two for...in's within a single list comprehension before. What's happening there?

Answer (score 0):

If your script is a utility, I suggest you to define a function like this in your `.bashrc` to call it in a directory:

```
myscript() {
   python /path/myscript.py "$@"
}
```

Then the whole list is passed to your python and you can process them like:

```
for _file in sys.argv[1:]:
    # do something on file
```