# Azure-Pipelines Build - refer to files in build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build my python based artifact in Azure DevOps.
I'm working on windows agent.
Here is structure of my code:

```
+-- Dir1
+----Version1
+------Build
+--------build.yaml
+------Script
+--------test_file.py
+--------file.py
+------Docs
```

During my build pipeline I try to run command like below:

```
python $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Dir1\Version1\Script\test_**
```

I receive error:

```
python: can't open file 'd:\a\1\s\Dir1\Version1\Script\test_**': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

When I refer to file directly it's working.
Does anyone have idea why these asterisk's / wildcards are not working correctly?

Comment: why would it work with an asterisk?

Comment: I thought that it's working like wildcard?

Comment: because shells do not work like that? you need to do it inside the python code if you want some sort of globbing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure-Pipelines Build - refer to files in build

That because **windows' command interpreter does not expand wildcards as UNIX shells do before passing them to the executed program or script**.

To resolve this issue, you could use the `glob` module, which provides a platform-independent way of doing wildcard matching.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405652/passing-arguments-with-wildcards-to-a-python-script) and [the document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) for some more details.

BTW, if you are using windows 10, you can use the wildcards with Bash task.

Hope this helps.